# Dockerfile setup for both production and development?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm wondering how people go about using docker for both production and development. In development I want to mount my source/build files to be able to quickly and easily make changes. For production, I want to include the source/build files in the image.

How is this typically done and is there a best or more common practice?

In my mind, ideally I would have one Dockerfile that uses something like a flag or environment variable to setup a prod or dev image, but I can't find any examples of people doing this and I am not sure how exactly it would be done.

I've also seen a few rough examples of projects with unique Dockerfiles for production and development, but then there is the issue of maintaining separate Dockerfiles which could diverge over time if we aren't careful.

Are both of these sensible or am I possibly misunderstanding something? I'm relatively new to docker. An example Dockerfile or project utilizing a similar setup would be great. I wary of dockerizing some of our services with bad practices at the start.

Edit: All my current apps are python base if that affects any responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the great answer by Kevin Wittek, it turns out this may have been more of a non issue.

I can use `COPY` to copy the files to the image, but I can simply mount over top of them for development.

If there's other things like dev-only deps that need to get installed, I can use `ARG` to specify environments like like `ARG APP_ENV=prod` and overwrite that with `--build-arg=dev` or vice-versa.

Comment: There's one caveat: Dockerfiles _must_ begin with a `FROM` statement. So if you need to build on a different base image, as I currently do, you cannot use this approach as you cannot run the `ARG` statement before the `FROM` statement.

Comment: @RichardDunn depending on the complexity, you could still use args and overwrite what the base image wrote. It may not be super efficient, but I don't see why it wouldn't work

Comment: True. I'm curious if you can use FROM twice for the same base image. Assuming you can, I imagine it'll just used the same cached version, so perhaps not too inefficient after all.

Comment: @RichardDunn You CAN use ARG statements before FROM. Maybe it's relatively new though. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

Answer (score 5):

A good aproach is to use Docker's [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/), since they will allow you to build your artifact inside an image that contains your dev dependencies and only use your artifact and runtime dependencies in the final image.

I'd generally advise against using different Dockerfiles for different environments, this should normally be achieved using configuration parameters (environment variables are a good solution).

Having a faster development feedback cycle depends IMO heavily on the used language. Many people will develop using an IDE, in a more classic fashion and only build the image for integration testing and so on (in my experience this is for example often the case for Java developers). Other interpreted languages might indeed profit from mounting your sources into a development environment image. In this case, you might incorperate this image into your multi-stage build.

Comment: That's somewhat reassuring since I was leaning that way. Could you give a little more detail on using configuration parameters? I may be misunderstanding something. So within a dockerfile, you can trigger different stages using something such as an environment variable?

Comment: You would normally use the environment variables for runtime configuration, when starting/creating the actual container that is based on this image. Also see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables. For actually making use of the environment variables for configuring the application, you need to build it into your application. See https://12factor.net/config

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. My root issue here is creating the image though. For dev, I want to mount my local filesystem with the source while for dev I want to include the source with the image. My apps are currently all python based, so I don't need to build anything. Rereading your solution, you advise against multiple dockerfiles but also mention incorporating a development image. Wouldn't this require multiple dockerfiles? One for development and one for production, which incorporates the development image?

Comment: I don't understand, shouldn't in an ideal world, all the previous stages of a docker multi-stage build be done through Jenkins and then a final build would be done with docker?